# Automatically launch gksudo when user doesn't have write permissions?

Tags: nautilus, gksu

Is it possible to automatically launch gksudo whenever I open a text file without write permissions in Nautilus? I often need to edit my /etc/hosts file and sometimes I forget to right click and select "Open as administrator".

Comment: Are you looking for a solution like `nautilus-gksu`, which adds an "Open as administrator" item to the context menu, or are you already using it and want a way to do this without using the context menu?

Comment: I'm already using it. I'd like not having to right click every time as I often forget. It would be nice if it just would be the default double click action for non writeable files.

Comment: report a wishlist bug - it would be awesome to add this as a feature.

Answer (score 3):

```
#!/bin/bash
EDITOR=gedit
SUDO=gksu-polkit
test -w "$1" || exec $SUDO $EDITOR "$1"
exec $EDITOR "$1"
```

Paste that in a file, make executable, and set as default to open whatever files you like.  Change the variables if you have a different editor or sudo program..  (Personally, I like gksu-polkit, from the package of the same name, better than gksudo, just because it doesn't grab my screen.)

I assume you know how to do all that; I'm more than happy to help if you don't.